# 1136: Incorrect number of arguments. Expected 1

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, timer

I have a function that adds an item to a random location to a grid (this is done on a timer event) and in this function i have a check that sees if the item hits the player. and if it does it calls the function. however it gives me the error when i call that function again. it might be because the function is a (event:TimerEvent)?

below is the function

```
 private function placeFood(event:TimerEvent = null):void{   
        var rndI:uint = Math.floor(Math.random() * DIM);  //sets a random integer based on the the floor
        var rndJ:uint = Math.floor(Math.random() * DIM);

        var rndX:Number = grid[rndI][rndJ].x; // sets a grid position for the food item to go
        var rndY:Number = grid[rndI][rndJ].y;

        if(_foodMap[int(rndX)] == null){
         _foodMap[rndX] = [];
        }

        if(_foodMap[int(rndX)][int(rndY)] == null){
         _foodMap[rndX][rndY] = food;
        }




        food = makeItem(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);// random color
        food.x = rndX;
        food.y = rndY;


        addChild(food); //adds the food to the board


        for (var i:uint = 0; i < snake.length; i++){
            if (rndY == snake[i].y && rndX == snake[i].x){ 
                placeFood();
            }
        } 
        }
```

Comment: change placeFood(); to placeFood(event);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call the function manually without the TimerEvent which the function is expecting you will get the error. So you need to define that the param's default value is null:

```
private function placeFood(event:TimerEvent = null):void {
    //code
}
```

For the food map create the multidimensional array which will contains the references to foods.

```
private var _foodMap:Array = [];
```

Then in the place when you add the food then also add it to the food map like i did below so you could check if the location where the snake's head is is empty.

```
if(_foodMap[int(rndX)] == null){
    _foodMap[rndX] = [];
}

if(_foodMap[int(rndX)][int(rndY)] == null){
    _foodMap[rndX][rndY] = food;
}
```

Then if both `_foodMap[int(snakesHeadX)] == null` and `_foodMap[int(snakesHeadX)][int(snakesHeadY)] == null` then it means the location of snake's head is empty.

Comment: perfect. cheers, you wouldnt know how i could code it so when the object (snake hits the food) it traces something?

Comment: @DIM3NSION, you need to know how to trace something or how to make a listener for the event when snake hits the food? If you need to trace something use `trace("Tracing something..");`. P.S. Pick the answer. (:

Comment: how would i code the listener? for when the snake hits the food? Thanks Richards

Comment: @DIM3NSION, do you have some code for snake hitting the food already?

Comment: i have - 
     if (Math.floor(s.x) == Math.floor(food.x) && Math.floor(s.y) == Math.floor(food.y) ){ trace("hit")
     } 
     else if((tmr.currentCount % 3) > 0) { removeChild(snake[0]); snake.shift(); }
   }. but that just checks the food object that has just been added to the stage not the other food objects

Comment: The snake can hit the food with it's head right? I guess you should keep up a map with the food locations. Then while the snake is moving check if the snake's head location (x, y) in the food map is not null. If it is null then there is no food in this location, right? If it's not null, then there is some food. You can store the food instances in the map so you could access the food item you your snake hit in case you need it.

Comment: How would i go about storing the food locations?  and yeah the primary aim is to not hit the food with the head but if it does the game ends.

Comment: Create a multidimensional array somewhere in your class and save the food's rndX and rndY in it when you create the foods. Then while the snake is moving check the location in the food map.

Comment: like this - foodLocations = new Array(new Array(rndX), new Array(rndY));

Comment: tried to achieve what your on about, might be completely wrong? -       foodLocations = new Array(new Array(rndX), new Array(rndY));
   
   for (var i:uint= o; i< foodLocations.length; i++) {
     if(Math.floor(s.x) == Math.floor(rndX) && Math.floor(s.y) == Math.floor(rndY)) { trace("hit")  }}
      } 
   }
}

Comment: See my answer, edited it and added the small foodMap example.

Comment: ive added that food map variable to the list of private vars and added the two if statements to the placeFood function. I don't quite understand how to check if the snakes head hits the the location though. ive ammended my post with what i have done. Any pointers from here?

Answer (score 1):

If you are giving a function to an event listener then the definition needs to match what the listener expects.

This:

```
private function placeFood(event:TimerEvent):void{
```

Will match a TIMER_EVENT, but no other events.

If you want other events to call this listener, change it to read:

```
private function placeFood(event:Event):void{
```

Answer (score 0):

Use placeFood(Event);  that's with a capital E.